# Flaresolverr timeout

Tags: docker

Installed Flaresolverr on docker.

When I try to retrieve the content of a site that has Cloudflare installed, I get a timeout error. The maximum timeout is set to 100000, but no matter what value you set, a timeout error is returned.

```
'{"status": "error", "message": "Error: Error solving the challenge. Timeout after 60.0 seconds.", "startTimestamp": 1707039887774, "endTimestamp": 1707039949768, "version": "3.3.13"}'
```

Please tell me, maybe this needs to be configured somehow additionally?
Maybe there are some features that I don't know about?

Get website content through flaresolverr without errors and timeouts